# What is the time and space complexity of unidirectional bfs and bidirectional bfs?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, space-complexity, graph-traversal

How do time and space complexity compare for unidirectional bfs and bi-directional bfs in worst and practical case such as a social network?

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: This is what I think, correct me if I am wrong.

For Worst Case:
Time complexity and space complexity will be the same for both. O(|E|+|V|).

In a practical scenario like a social network, shortest path between two nodes:
bidirectional will get the result faster and use less space, but I can't deduct the exact time and space complexities.

Comment: I'd like to try to provide an answer to your question, but other than rather low *diameters* (maximum shortest distance between any pair of vertices) and maybe large *branching factors*, what do you think that better characterizes a social network?

Comment: that's all I can think of